# получение зависимостей Gradle из Wildfly

Tags: java, postgresql, java-ee, wildfly

Ситуация следующая:

Есть postgreSQL сервер на который я посылаю зарос. Запрос возращает таблицу с полем формата interval. Для приема данных такого поля существует класс org.postgresql.util.PGInterval, а принимать такое значения надо примерно следующим образом: `(org.postgresql.util.PGInterval) rs.getObject("interval").`

К базе подключаюсь через DataSourse

module.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.postgresql" slot="main">
        <resources>
            <resource-root path="postgresql-9.4.1208.jre7.jar"/>
        </resources>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.api"/>
            <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
        </dependencies>
    </module>
```

standalone.xml
...

```
 <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:/Test" pool-name="Test" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
                        <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/PUP_P</connection-url>
                        <driver-class>org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource</driver-class>
                        <connection-property name="serverName">
                            127.0.0.1
                        </connection-property>
                        <connection-property name="databaseName">
                            Test
                        </connection-property>
                        <connection-property name="portNumber">
                            5432
                        </connection-property>
                        <connection-property name="prepareThreshold">
                            3
                        </connection-property>
                        <driver>postgresql</driver>
                        <pool>
                            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                            <initial-pool-size>1</initial-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>true</prefill>
                        </pool>
                        <security>
                            <user-name>uset</user-name>
                            <password>pass</password>
                        </security>
                        <validation>
                            <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                            <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                            <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.postgres.PostgreSQLExceptionSorter"/>
                        </validation>
                    </datasource>
```

...

В Java

```
  @Resource(lookup = "java:/Test")
  DataSource dts;
    try (Connection con = newDS.getConnection();
//и т.д.
```

Но. Если я пишу далее например

```
 org.postgresql.util.PGInterval var =  new org.postgresql.util.PGInterval();
```

то IDEA сообщает мне, что в проекте нет такой библиотеки и надо ее импортнуть. Можно конечно импортнуть нужную библиотеку вручную (с gradle), но только если не угадать с версией org.postgresql.util.PGInterval не будет работать, а поэтому надо как то получить org.postgresql.util.PGInterval из JDBC, указанного в  module.xml. Как это сделать?

PS: Даже если версии библиотек совпадают `(org.postgresql.util.PGInterval) rs.getObject("interval").` выдаст ошибку, т.к. это будут разные классы.

Насколько я понимаю ошибку можно устранить указав gradle брать  compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4-1203-jdbc42' из wildfly, а как это сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нужно сделать прожект зависимым от нужной версии postgresql, но только во время компиляции. Т.е. в собранном прожекте не должно быть postgresql-я.
2. У wildfly свои правила загрузки классов. В документации есть описание как работает и как настроить. Точно не скажу, но скорей всего так должно сработать.
   Создать файл `WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml` с такой начинкой

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
      <deployment>
        <dependencies>
           <module name="org.postgresql"/>
        </dependencies>
     </deployment>    
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```

Если что, курите мануалы по wildfly. Может потребуется какие-нибудь ещё атрибуты указать в элементе `module` кроме собственно имени модуля.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Первый пункт не понял как  делать

Comment: @Dmitrii Ничем не могу помочь. использую `maven`, там такая зависимость имеет `scope` = `provided`. C `gradle`-м как сборщиком прожектов никогда дел не имел, но должна быть аналогичная функциональность.

Comment: Получилось. в градле написал просто compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '9.4-1203-jdbc42'

Comment: Спасибо, весь день на это убил